# Function pointer initialization won't compile

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to initialize a function pointer variable in order to pass it as a parameter to a constructor that takes a function pointer.

I've tried just about every version of this declaration I've been able to find online, and all of them have given me compilation errors.

```
// the functions
void *OthelloBoard::GetOptions() const { return nullptr; }
void OthelloBoard::SetOptions(const void *data) {}

// the function pointers
void *(OthelloBoard::*GetOptionsPtr)() const = &OthelloBoard::GetOptions;
void (OthelloBoard::*SetOptionsPtr)(const void *) = &OthelloBoard::SetOptions;

// the constructor 
BoardClass(void (*setOptions)(const void *), void *(*getOptions)()) {}

// the constructor call
BoardClass OthelloBoard::mClass(SetOptionsPtr, GetOptionsPtr);
```

I expected the variables to compile, and to properly pass, but I was given this error:

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'void (OthelloBoard::*)(const void *)' with an rvalue of type 'void (*)(const void *)'

void (OthelloBoard::*SetOptionsPtr)(const void *) = &OthelloBoard::SetOptions;
                     ^                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Is `SetOptions` a static member function?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm it is a non-static member function

Comment: @WhozCraig how should i be formatting the constructor parameters in order to pass GetOptions and SetOptions? I thought I had the signature right..

Comment: A pointer to member function and a pointer to function are *not* equivalent. Frankly, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm trying to pass a pointer to member functions GetOptions and SetOptions to the constructor of BoardClass.

Comment: @PatrickBartlett that won't work, since the constructor doesn't accept pointer-to-member-function as input parameters. You need to find a different solution.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Maybe you can convert that to an answer.